# Get sent emails copy in inbox

Tags: gmail

In Gmail, whenever I send an email I want to get a copy of the message that I sent in my inbox, 100% of the time. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found a way to add the inbox label to all outgoing messages. But you can use "multiple inboxes" to get sent mail to the top of the window

1. Go to settings/Labs and select "Multiple inboxes"
2. Save Changes
3. You should now see a "Multiple inboxes" tab in settings.
4. GMail will let you specify a search query. In the first box enter "is:Sent Mail" without the quotes.
5. Set the maximum page size to a larger number. It didn't complain about using 50, but I don't know if there is a maximum value.
6. Optional: Set "Extra panels positioning" to Above the inbox. This will put the "Sent Mail" label above the main inbox.
7. Save changes

There may be a couple of second lag the first time you go back to the main page, becuse it has to execute the new query.

It does the job with a couple of issues:

- Each inbox has its own < and > button to move through the list
- Each inbox has its own "view all" button which jumps you to the label
- The gear button is only on the tool bar above the main inbox section.

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a filter for messages sent from: [yourself], and check *Never send it to spam*.
This will put all sent emails in your inbox automatically.

Comment: This is the best solution here by far. In fact, I had done this but did not realise it was the reason my sent emails were in my inbox, which i really like as I had made the filter for another reason.  All the above work-arounds are not as good as this one.

Comment: Appreciate this answer! :)

Comment: Do you mean to put the literal string "[yourself]" into the Filter "From" box?  Because that seems wrong, at least in the web app.  Using a value of "me" makes marginally more sense, maybe, or did you mean that your actual email address(es) should go here?

Comment: Update: "me" seems to work.  Alternatively you can start in the search bar with "from:me".

Comment: I'd guess they meant actual email address. I found this post because I'd set my own email address as never to go to spam, having used a different mail server to send email from my own email address and having had to dig it out of spam. Getting a copy of every sent item in my inbox as a result wasn't what I expected.

Comment: I don't know why, but it works! Checked against GSuite.

Answer (score 1):

As a previous person answered, create a filter on emails sent from your email address. For the action, select 'Never send to Spam'. I do not know why the person was downvoted, but I have used this technique with no problems for years. I just set up a new account and verified that it continues to function as before.

Comment: Previous person? who? This should be a comment on the answer you are referring.

Answer (score 0):

You can't mess with the default inbox view, unfortunately.

My solution was to search for: "in:inbox OR is:sent", then bookmark that URL.  You will notice that by default, the regular emails have the "Inbox" label, and the sent emails lack the label.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, if Gmail has a tool for that but i just sent the copy of the message back to me using the Add Bcc in the compose window.